# Regular expressions: Search a word and append a new word at the end of the line

Tags: linux, perl, sed

I have some TCL Files which contain many lines like this.

```
unp classification ip-address $env(SOURCE_IP4) mask 255.255.255.0
```

Unfortunately I forget to put a word(edge-profile) at the end. It should be like this.

```
unp classification ip-address $env(SOURCE_IP4) mask 255.255.255.0 edge-profile.
```

Can someone tell me how to search the line by the keyword `"unp classification ip-address"` and append the word "edge-profile" at the end of the lines. I need to change multiple files. A one line perl or sed script will be good.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i '/unp classification ip-address/s/$/ edge-profile/' *.tcl
```

Comment: if the line matches `unp classification ip-address` then sed executes the following command, which adds `edge-profile` at the end of that line.

Comment: @fedorqui The expression `s/$/ edge-profile/` is applied on lines matching the specified pattern.

Comment: So `s/$/ something/` means add "something" at the end of the line. Interesting, thanks @devnull and perreal

Comment: @fedorqui yes, s is for substitution, $ is regex for end-of-line and " something" is the replacement string

Comment: @fedorqui, no, it is the substitution command, replaces the first the part between the first slashes with the part between the 2nd and 3rd slashes. The `$` is the end of line marker, and this expression replaces the end of the line with `something`. But the end of the lines is not consumed.

Comment: Oh, now I see. It is a good trick then to use `$` in these cases to append text at the end of the line. Thanks everyone!